# What happens to a null byte when converting bytes to ISO 8859-1 encoding?

Tags: c#, encoding, id3, iso-8859-1

I'm not entirely sure if the question even makes sense. I'm converting a byte array taken from an ID3 tag and converting it to a string. Most text frames in an ID3 tag use ISO 8859-1 encoding but it depends on the frame. In any case, if you look up what 0x00 is in the ISO 8859-1 codes it is invalid.

To further complicate, either due programmer error or just poor formatting, some of the strings end in 0x00 and some do not.

When converting a series of bytes into a string using ISO 8859-1 encoding do you have manually check the end of the string to see if it is a null? Or will the encoding object through whatever method it uses to convert in the first place deal with the null properly? Furthermore, is there some sort of function that could normalize or "fix" the null terminated string?

When you try to display these strings they do not display properly.

I am using C# for this particular project.
Some extra info here about ID3 Tags: [ID3 Specs](http://www.id3.org/id3v2.3.0#head-1a37d4a15deafc294208ccfde950f77e47000bca)

Or am I completely misunderstanding the whole thing? Is a null terminator simply a way a particular language handles strings and it has nothing to do with encoding?

- Edit: I used System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") followed by a GetString call

Comment: If you are converting you will be transforming data from one representation to another. You've said what you are converting to. What are you converting from. You didn't say that.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)`, it just converts a byte 0 to the Unicode U+0000. Encodings generally assume that they have to convert all the bytes - they don't look for terminators.

This treatment of 0 as Unicode 0 is inline with the [Wikipedia description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1):

> In 1992, the IANA registered the character map ISO_8859-1:1987, more commonly known by its preferred MIME name of ISO-8859-1 (note the extra hyphen over ISO 8859-1), a superset of ISO 8859-1, for use on the Internet. This map assigns the [C0 and C1 control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_character) to the unassigned code values thus provides for 256 characters via every possible 8-bit value.

The C0 and C1 control characters page includes:

> 0: Originally used to allow gaps to be left on paper tape for edits. Later used for padding after a code that might take a terminal some time to process (e.g. a carriage return or line feed on a printing terminal). Now often used as a string terminator, especially in the C programming language.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] data = { 0, 0 };
        Encoding latin1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);

        string text = latin1.GetString(data);
        Console.WriteLine(text.Length); // 2
        Console.WriteLine((int) text[0]); // 0
        Console.WriteLine((int) text[1]); // 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Happily, ASCII, ISO-8859-1 and Unicode all agree on codepoints in the range 0..127. Thus your character `'\0'` will be encoded identically in ASCII, ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8.

If your program assigns special semantics to the zero byte, you have to take care of that appropriately.

Comment: Ok. So yes  0x00 gets converted to '\0'. But when converting a series of bytes (that end in 0x00) should the null be included? Or would this result in a string having 2 null terminators? For example, would C# add another null terminator to the end of the string? In any case, after I display such a string it screws up the display of all other strings.

Comment: It depends entirely on whether you're working with a function that interprets byte strings as null-terminated character strings or not. Check your documentation. I don't know C#, but in C the string functions do stop at a null byte, while in C++ the string class is entirely indifferent about the value of the bytes.